# Add Control after Items in GridView Group

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I'm currently developing a Windows 8 Store app that uses a Grouped GridView in the HubPage showing Highlights for some Categories. So far, when clicking the Header you see More Highlights for this Category.

Now i want to add a control at the end of every Group leading the User to the "non-highlight" Category site, where just all the Items of this category are displayed.

Is there an easy and elegant way to do this - propably with a Template is suppose.

( i think the latest Bing-News-App has a similar feature )

Thanks in advance for every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.

- You can add an arbitrary object to the end of your group, then use a DataTemplateSelector to style it.
- You can create your own VariableSizedWrapGrid with the control added to the end in the constructor (slash "Arrange"). You can then add an arbitrary click handler as a dependency property and only show the button if the click handler is set, so you can reuse this on other pages, etc.
- You can change the GroupStyle to include something similar at the end of the group, but it likely won't animate with the other items in the group (if that's important to you).

The easiest one to do is probably the first one. If your group is a list of `SampleItems` then make a subclass of the `SampleItem` class called something similar to `TerminalSampleItem`. Create a template for it (like you've made other data templates). Make an `ItemTemplateSelector` that has two properties, `NonTerminalDataTemplate` and `TerminalDataTemplate` (assuming you only have two data templates). Have the `SelectTemplateOverride` function check for (`item is TerminalSampleItem`);

Comment: Thanks!

I thought to add an arbitrary object but i figured it was a little bit weird concerning the seperation of code and xaml (i only consider it to be a navigation element like the header - with minor styles).

I'll get back to you :) Thanks!